# Dagster start pipeline from another pipeline using its outputs

Tags: python, pipeline, dagster

How am I supposed to start a pipeline B after pipeline A completes, and use pipeline A's outputs into pipeline B?

A piece of code as a starting point:

```
from dagster import InputDefinition, Nothing, OutputDefinition, pipeline, solid

@solid
def pipeline1_task1(context) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 1 task 1')


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("start", Nothing)],
       output_defs=[OutputDefinition(str, 'some_str')])
def pipeline1_task2(context) -> str:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 1 task 2')
    return 'my cool output'


@pipeline
def pipeline1():
    pipeline1_task2(pipeline1_task1())


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("print_str", str)])
def pipeline2_task1(context, print_str) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 2 task 1' + print_str)


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("start", Nothing)])
def pipeline2_task2(context) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 2 task 2')


@pipeline
def pipeline2():
    pipeline2_task2(pipeline2_task1())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run pipeline 1
    # store outputs
    # call pipeline 2 using the above outputs
```

Here we have three pipelines: `pipeline1` has two solids, possibly does whatever stuff we wish and returns output from the second solid. `pipeline2` is supposed to use the output of `pipeline1_task2`, eventually do another piece of work and print the output of the first pipeline.

How am I supposed to "connect" the two pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make one pipeline execute after another one is via a sensor.  The recommended way to do this in Dagster is with an "asset sensor".  A solid in the first pipeline yields an `AssetMaterialization`, and the sensor in the second pipeline waits for that asset to be materialized.

Here's an example: https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/sensors#asset-sensors

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, I came to the following solution (not too elegant in my opinion, but at least it works):

```
from dagster import (InputDefinition, OutputDefinition,
                     execute_pipeline, pipeline, solid, Nothing, repository)


@solid
def pipeline1_task1(context) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 1 task 1')


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("start", Nothing)],
output_defs=[OutputDefinition(str, 'some_str')])
def pipeline1_task2(context) -> str:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 1 task 2')
    return '\n\n\nmy cool output\n\n\n'


@pipeline
def pipeline1():
    pipeline1_task2(pipeline1_task1())


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("print_str", str)])
def pipeline2_task1(context, print_str) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 2 task 1' + print_str)


@solid(input_defs=[InputDefinition("start", Nothing)])
def pipeline2_task2(context) -> Nothing:
    context.log.info('in pipeline 2 task 2')


@pipeline
def pipeline2():
    pipeline2_task2(pipeline2_task1())


@solid
def run_pipelines(context):
    pout = execute_pipeline(pipeline1)
    some_str = pout.result_for_solid('pipeline1_task2')
    conf = {'solids': {'pipeline2_task1': {'inputs': {'print_str': some_str.output_value('some_str')}}}}
    execute_pipeline(pipeline2, run_config=conf)

@pipeline
def pipeline3():
    run_pipelines()


@repository
def repo():
    return [pipeline1, pipeline2, pipeline3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute_pipeline(pipeline3)
```

So... here I've defined `pipeline3` instead of doing everything in the bottom conditional. Pipeline 3 has only one solid, which executes `pipeline1` and gets the output of the solid `pipeline1_task2`. It then creates a configuration that includes that output, `some_str`, and passes this configuration to the `execute_pipeline` for the second pipeline.

Here, we have also defined an `@repository` function, which is necessary for Dagster to figure out that all three pipelines are part of a whole.

The whole thing visualizes nicely in `dagit`. Although each pipeline is shown separately from the others, the three are shown in one repository (as defined in the code).
[image]